# UIDatePicker + NSDate returns Null value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I'm using a `UIDatePicker` in Xcode 8/Objective-C to have the user select a birth date which will then be sent to my sql database. In order to do this I want to convert it to a string so I can add it to the insert statement. The problem is that my code seems to be returning either the value (null) or nothing at all which crashes my program.

My .h file:

```
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *myDatePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *myDatePicker;
```

My .m file:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:myDatePicker.date]];
```

I've tried many variations of the above code including `NSDate *chosen = [mydatepicker date]` and trying to convert that, but again I either end up with (null) in my database or an empty cell that crashes the program.

Comment: Most likely you have not connected the date picker to your `myDatePicker` outlet.

Comment: @rmaddy You sir were exactly correct. I feel like an idiot for sure, figured that using mydatepicker.date would specify the picker i am using but I guess not, connecting the outlet worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @rmaddy "Most likely you have not connected the date picker to your myDatePicker outlet". He was right. Went into my storyboard, lo and behold there was an outlet there that had not been connected.

Comment: In iOS/Mac OS development, when something doesn't work that seems like it should the first rule is check your outlet and action connections. The second rule is also to check your outlet and action connections. :) You have to get bitten by this a couple of dozen times before you stop wasting hours on it.

Answer (score 0):

In case, your storyboard has many control and complex

The simple way to make sure you don't miss anything by using NSAssert

Example

```
NSAssert(yourcontrol, @"IBOutlet not set for yourcontrol");
```

It will be crashed to notice you . It will save your time when working